# Mapping to a CFC in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, mapping, cfc

In my application I have all my CFC's in a cfc folder. From the site root I can access them without any trouble by simply referring to them in my `<cfinvoke>` tag as `component=cfc.mycomponent method=mymethod`

The trouble is, when I want to access the cfc from another page that's not in the root I can't use `component=../.cfc.mycomponent` to get in touch with that cfc.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Last I checked, that kind of relative path was not supported. From that location, you need to use an absolute path from the root ie `root.cfc.mycomponent`

Comment: FYI: Here is how CF searches for components: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e17.html

Comment: Thanks Leigh. I'm using CF8 for this particular site. I did notice that the instructions seemed somewhat similar.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are a handful of options for getting this to work. Unfortunately, learning them has taken me a good amount of trial and error. Let me share what I've learned.

**First**, you can use the classic method of creating a mapping in your CF Administrator. Specify the exact path to your components (e.g. `c:\wwwroot\cfc`), and the mapping (pseudo-folder) that you want to call it by (e.g. `MyCFCs`). Now from anywhere in your application, you can reference create a `new MyCFCs.mycomponent()` (using CF9+'s `new` keyword, you can substitute for createObject("component","MyCFCs.mycomponent") to be compatible back to CF6).

The downsides to using a server mapping are that you have to configure this on every server your application runs on. I typically have a local development server which has a radically different configuration from my production servers, and making changes on production servers is a pain for me, so I try to avoid server mappings whenever possible.

**Second**, you can reference your CFCs from a web-root-relative path, meaning that if your application is in the root of your server and the `/cfc` path is directly off of the web root, you can always do `new cfc.mycomponent()` from anywhere in your application. ColdFusion 6.1 and up will correctly map to the root of your web site. This is like referencing an image using `/images/mypicture.jpg`, anywhere in your web site, `/images` will will go straight to the same directory.

The downside of using the web-root-relative path is that if your application will ever be in a different folder off of the web root, or will ever be in a subdirectory and sometimes be at the web root, the relative path from the web root will change, breaking these links.

**Third**, you can create an application-specific mapping. This was introduced in CF8 and requires that you have an `Application.cfc` file. It is simple to add. Raymond Camden has [a great reference](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/downloads/application.cfc.txt). The syntax is essentially like this.

```
<cfset this.name = "MyAppName"/>
<cfset this.mappings = structNew() />
<cfset this.mappings["/cfc"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) & "cfc/" />
```

The only downside to this method is that your Application.cfc can't extend a CFC in a mapped folder. It's an obscure problem, which probably won't affect you. Also, you will need to have an Application.cfc, which is good practice, but I don't know if you are doing that yet.

**Fourth**, you can instantiate your CFC into your application scope, probably from within the aforementioned Application.cfc, inside an `OnApplicationStart()` method. This moves any compile/instantiation time into your application's first hit, and removes it from subsequent hits. The code is very simple.

```
<!--- from Application.cfc, inside onApplicationStart() --->
<cfset application.myComponent = new cfc.myComponent() />

<!--- from anywhere else in your application --->
<cfset application.myComponent.callMyMethod() />
```

The downside to this one is that once your component is in Application memory, any changes you make to it while you are developing your application will not be reflected until you clear the application memory or call onApplicationStart() again. It's not hard to get around, but it's just more code, and more to manage.

**One final note**, you may want to think about moving from `<cfinvoke>` to `createObject("component",...)` or, if you are on CF9, `new`. The cfinvoke syntax is fine, but every time you invoke a component from a path, you are re-instantiating it, and it also is not a very object-oriented way to call your components. Food for thought, take it or leave it :)

Comment: Incredible detail and helpful description in lay terms. Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to report back on this. I've implemented option 3 and it works famously. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm probably too late on this but, can I use the third option to map other folders as well, such as my scripts and images folders?

Comment: It works for server-side resources, but not for client-side files. You can do add a virtual directory through your web server, or through CF, you can construct a web-root-relative link to your scripts & images folders, and use that. From your Application.cfc, something like: `<cfset application.imagePath = replace(expandPath("images/"), expandPath("."), "") />` then reference it as `#application.imagePath#/myPhoto.jpg` - I'm not testing this, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use relative paths with components.

What you need is a ColdFusion mapping. There are two ways to do this.

The first is to go into your ColdFusion administrator, go into the mappings section and add a /cfc mapping that points to your cfc folder.

The other way is to use application specific mappings;
In the Application.cfc for your application you can add application mappings as you would under the ColdFusion administrator mapping.  At the top of your application cfc add a cfset of this.mappings as an array. In this array set the mapping with the directory path.

```
<cfset this.mappings["/cfc"] = GetDirectoryFromPath( GetCurrentTemplatePath() )&"cfc">
```

with the mapping of /cfc to your cfc folder any component calls to cfc.objectname will load the appropriate component in your cfc folder.

Comment: It must be `<cfset this.mappings["/cfc"] = ...` - you forgot the "s".

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can extend a cfc with mappings. I had to do it myself.

One of the most frustrating things that I have had to deal with in ColdFusion is trying to create an external application that is open to the general public and having to secure a portion of that site with an application within a subfolder and extending the logic from base application.cfc. I'll walk you through the current approach that developers use to solve this as well as showing you how to additionally use mapping when there may be a hosting provider that uses virtual directories.

This is a rather long article, if you want to jump to the condensed summary, scroll down to the bottom of this page.

Many years ago, the first time that I tried to perform this, I received the following message no matter what I tried: **"Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface xxx'**. In a nutshell, the problem using this approach is that both the root and the subfolders have the same name, i.e. Application.cfc, and ColdFusion can't properly identify what component to extend. Finally, after some serious investigation, someone came up with the idea to create a proxy.cfc that resides in the same root directory as the root Application.cfc, and the Application.cfc in the subfolder extends an empty proxy.cfc that extends the root cfc like so:

**root directory: Application.cfc**
This root Application.cfc **does not extend anything**

**Also in the root directory: Proxy.cfc**
Proxy.cfc has the following code, it's **essentially empty**. The **only** thing that the **Proxy.cfc** does is to extend the Application.cfc that is in the same directory:

<cfcomponent extends="Application">
</cfcomponent>

**Subdirectory** such as a folder named admin.
This subdirectory has another **Application.cfc**. Let's say that this component is responsible for securing the application and has login logic as well as debugging settings for example. **This Application.cfc** will extend the **Proxy.cfc** to gain the methods and properties of the Application.cfc in the root directory like so:

<cfcomponent displayname="Admin" extends="Proxy.cfc">

This approach was a godsend and it was heavily blogged about. **Ben Nadel** has made a number of very helpful posts which I will share at the bottom of this article.

This works quite well unless you're on a hosted domain or a server that uses **virtual directories**. In this case, we are in the same original boat in which we started from. Now we are back into the **"Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface xxx' hell!**

**There is a solution for this tricky problem though, we need to also use mapping!**

It is a common misnomer that you can't use mapping to extend components. I am not quite sure where this misconception originally came about, but it has been proven that this is just not true. There are occasions where we **must** use mapping to solve some annoying problems, like here.

This particular site is hosted by [hostek.com](https://www.hostek.com). **They are a fine company to deal with**, but the server that my site is hosted on has some idiosyncrasies due to the directory structure. Here, when I use the Proxy.cfc method to extend the logic from the base Application.cfc to the Application.cfc in the admin folder I receive the dreaded 'could not find the ... component' error. When I first saw it I was dismayed thinking not this again, so I turned to ColdFusion CFC mapping. Mapping tells ColdFusion where to find the file and what the file relationships are.

Let's review CFC structure that was just discussed. For example, imagine the following directory structure:

root directory: i.e. [www.gregoryalexander.com/](http://www.gregoryalexander.com/)
subdirectory: [www.gregoryalexander.com/admin/](http://www.gregoryalexander.com/admin/)

As discussed, we have an **Application.cfc** and the **Proxy.cfc** in the **root directory**, and we have the **Application.cfc** in the 'admin' **subdirectory**.
The Proxy.cfc extends the Application.cfc, also in the root directory, and the Application.cfc in the subdirectory (admin) extends the Proxy.cfc in the root directory.

root directory: contains both Application.cfc and Proxy.cfc (that extends the root Application.cfc).
subdirectory: Application.cfc (that extends Proxy.cfc).

Now we need to also add the following mapping in the root Application.cfc. This mapping logic should be near **the top of the root Application.cfc**, and it **should not** be within any of the Application.cfc event handlers (onApplicationStart, onApplicationRequest, etc). This mapping code does not need to be anywhere else other than the root Application.cfc:

<cfset this.mappings = structNew() />
<cfset this.mappings["rootCfc"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) />
<cfset this.mappings["adminCfc"] = getDirectoryFromPath( getCurrentTemplatePath() & "/admin" ) />

I used rootCfc to identify the Application.cfc in the root directory, whereas adminCfc applies to the Application in the admin directory. These variables can be named anything. Note that the "/admin" string at the end of the adminCfc mapping points to the 'admin' folder, which is a subdirectory.

Now that we have the mappings in the root Application.cfc, we need to apply them to the extends statement in Application.cfc located in the subdirectory. In the /admin/Application.cfc template use:

**/admin/Application.cfc**
<cfcomponent displayname="xxx" sessionmanagement="xx" clientmanagement="xx" extends="rootCfc.Proxy">

Of course, rootCfc tells the Application.cfc in the subdirectory to look for the Proxy.cfc template in the root directory. Like other 'extend' statements, you don't need to specify '.cfc' at the end of Proxy.

You don't need to use this 'extend' mapping in either the root Proxy.cfc or Application.cfc templates. They can already find each other as they are both in the same root directory.

**/Proxy.cfc**
<cfcomponent extends="Application">
</cfcomponent>

Summary

For the sake of absolute clarity:
**root Application.cfc**
Contains the mapping logic. Has the mappings for both of the root and subdirectory.
Does not use an 'extend' statement

<cfset this.mappings = structNew() />
<cfset this.mappings["rootCfc"] = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()) />
<cfset this.mappings["adminCfc"] = getDirectoryFromPath( getCurrentTemplatePath() & "/admin" ) />

**root Proxy.cfm**
A simple 'extends="Administrator" works.
No mapping logic.

<cfcomponent extends="Application">
</cfcomponent>

**subdirectory Application.cfc**
The extends statement must be the mapping variable name of the folder (rootCfc), a dot (.), and finally the name of the Proxy.cfc template without the .cfc prefix (Proxy)

<cfcomponent displayname="Admin" sessionmanagement="yes" clientmanagement="yes" extends="rootCfc.Proxy">

My apologies for being so verbose. I annoyed myself while writing this- but not as annoyed when I was while trying to solve this problem!

Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if your components extend other components the full path is used.

ie a Products controller

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Products" hint="Handles all product requests" extends="core.controller.controller"  output="false">
```