# Conflicting mapping for two ColdFusion Applications

Tags: coldfusion, relative-path

I've spent over a day now trying to resolve an issue where two applications use the same relative paths but are under a different "root", and this causes the wrong code base to be accessed for one of the applications.

These are my roots to the two Applications:

1. \www\Clients\
2. \www\Other\Clients\

**Structure**

```
..www 
....Clients 
......Application.cfc 
....Other 
......Clients 
........Application.cfc
```

In both Applications there is code that references the relative path (*e.g., /clients/content/login.cfm*)

I noticed that the ColdFusion Administrator has a Mappings section where the first mapping has a logical path `/` mapped to the directory path `D:/www/`.

This works well for the first application since the `clients` folder is found directly under the `www` folder, however the second application doesn't work correctly as it too adheres to the same mapping. Therefore instead of searching for `/clients/content/login.cfm` under the `Others` folder, it searches yet again under the `www` folder.

*Note:* Both applications have a different `Application.Name` so they are indeed segregated.

The biggest red flag is that we don't experience this issue on our older ColdFusion 9 server, however we are experiencing this on the newer ColdFusion 2016 server.

Sifting through ColdFusion Administrator, I can't seem to find any other settings which could affect the underlying root per Application which could take precedence over the Mappings.

Is there a setting I missed? Was there a drastic change regarding relative paths or mappings between ColdFusion 9 and ColdFusion 2016?

Comment: IIRC for older versions of ColdFusion we needed to have the root `/` mapping in the ColdFusion administrator to make things work. That should not be necessary anymore if you switch over to using application specific mappings (defined in your Application.cfc file). I would remove the administrator mapping and add an application specific mapping to your two Application.cfc files defining exactly where that application's files are located.

Comment: Application specific mapping did indeed resolve the situation, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sifting through ColdFusion Administrator, I can't seem to find any
>   other settings which could affect the underlying root per Application
>   which could take precedence over the Mappings.

**Solution:** Use application specific mappings.

```
<cfset this.mappings["/Clients"] = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath())>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814691/978864)