# Application.cfc Image mappings

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

This is probably something simple but I am struggling with it.

If in my application.cfc I have below

```
this.mappings = { "/foo" = expandPath('gfx/')
```

And I want to call said directory when pulling up an image

```
<img src="/foo/test.jpg" width="90" height="90" />
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: As miguel said - you don't need a coldFusion mapping - you need a virtual directory in IIS Or apache. src="/blah" does not trigger cf in any way. It's pushed to the browser where it is subsequently called through HTTP & IIS. Since the file is .JPG it will be served as an image. CF not in play.

Answer (score 5):

ColdFusion mappings only apply to ColdFusion code. Tags like `cfinclude`, `cfmodule`, or for [calling CFCs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814823/1636917), etc. What you are attempting to use it for is an HTML img `src` attribute which expects an absolute or relative URL. If you want similar functionality look into creating a [virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory) on your web server.

Of course there are many other things ColdFusion will allow you to do in [building that URL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c67.html) or [pushing an image to the browser](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/working-with-documents-charts-and-reports/creating-and-manipulating-coldfusion-images/writing-images-to-the-browser.html) but I think that answers your specific question here.